# partial match in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, search

i am making a search for for a website. what i am looking to do is find a simple way to allow for a partial search.
something like, if someone searches for 'abc' i want to be able to search of a 66% match.

```
select [itemNumber] 
from [items] 
where 
([description] like '%a%' and [description] like '%b%' and [description] like '%c%')
or
([description] like '%a%' and [description] like '%b%')
or
([description] like '%a%' and [description] like '%c%')
or
([description] like '%b%' and [description] like '%c%')
```

is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Maybe with [Full-Text indexes](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/understanding-full-text-indexing-in-sql-server/)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to make it in single row but this can simplify a little bit:

```
where [description] Like '%[abc]%' OR 
[description] Like '%[ab]%' OR
[description] Like '%[ac]%' OR
[description] Like '%[bc]%' OR
```

[Check this how we can use wildcards in sql server](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1044/available-wildcards-in-sql-server-with-examples)